# How to plot a JSON file generated by osrm for route optimization into an OSM map

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis, traveling-salesman, osrm

I am a complete newbie to computation of gps, gis and all these geoinformatical stuff. First I describe my lessons learned to arrive at gps data. **You can skip this and go to the last two paragraphs where I explain my problem with osrm and how to map a route onto an OSM map via qgis or similar tools.**

I tried to do some route optimization for a bunch of addresses to support my son's paper deliverer job. I was able to generate a list of gps data by using the Nomatim engine that is available via geopy.geocoders. It's kind of a Travelling Salesman problem (TSP).

By using geopy's distance calculator and the or-tools from Google to Generate a shortest list recommendation. That worked well but it was only a TSP solution for air line :-(.

Then I was looking for route optimization toolkits but i struggled to get one for free. I thought osrm could be the right tool. I followed the descriptions given at Github, see [here](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Running-OSRM). I was able to generate a JSON file - at least I supposed that it's kind of a JSON file. But I was unable to project this back onto a map in QGis or any online tool from OSM. Can anyone help me?

The file with such JSON-like formatting:

> {"code":"Ok","waypoints":[{"hint":"Jh4BgEUzI4BhAAAACwAAAKIAAABZAAAAkLAjQgpyikBay4dCWsuHQmEAAAALAAAAogAAAFkAAAArAAAAxwB4AARI3AI3AXgAWEbcAgIADwXVhXd1","location":...

Due to privacy issues I cannot post it here with any locations. Sorry for this. But does anyone have kind of a recipe / step-by-step guide what I need to do to plot it? I even have no idea how to "open" a map within qgis. You need to do this as kind of a database but this is totally new for me. I would prefer to work with an easier method to plot it.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the API documentation [here](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.22.0/api/#general-options). From that documentation

> hint Unique internal identifier of the segment (ephemeral, not
>   constant over data updates) This can be used on subsequent request to
>   significantly speed up the query and to connect multiple services.
>   E.g. you can use the hint value obtained by the nearest query as hint
>   values for route inputs.

You can get the geometry in many ways. Widely GeoJSON is being used by developers. OSRM returns a very clean GeoJSON which can easily be used with Leaflet, Mapbox or other Map APIs. You need to send `steps` parameter `true` to get the full step by step direction. You can get the each segments of steps in `legs`. So call the GeoJSON within the geometries of every legs with loop. You can also get the geometry without passing the `steps` parameter true. For that you will get full geometry in a single GeoJSON within the routes property.